# Как пользоваться AnimationGroup?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой что для использования AnimationGroup  мне постоянно нужно создавать новый `QVariantAnimation`
и назначать ему все новые значения. можно ли более кратко это записать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.wid.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        self.wid.resize(100, 100)

        # animation
        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.group.setLoopCount(10)

        self.ani_1 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_1.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_1.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_1.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutSine)
        self.ani_1.setStartValue(0)
        self.ani_1.setEndValue(100)

        self.ani_2 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_2.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_2.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_2.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_2.setStartValue(100)
        self.ani_2.setEndValue(0)

        self.ani_3 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_3.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_3.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_3.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_3.setStartValue(0)
        self.ani_3.setEndValue(300)

        self.ani_4 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_4.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_4.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_4.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_4.setStartValue(300)
        self.ani_4.setEndValue(0)


        self.ani_5 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_5.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_5.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_5.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_5.setStartValue(0)
        self.ani_5.setEndValue(300)

        self.ani_6 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_6.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_6.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_6.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_6.setStartValue(300)
        self.ani_6.setEndValue(0)

        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_1)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_2)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_3)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_4)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_5)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_6)

        self.start_fun()

    def value_change(self, value):
        self.wid.move(0, value)

    def start_fun(self):
        self.group.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я знаю что можно просто использовать `self.ani_1.finished.connect(self.ani_1.start())`
Но я хочу свободно использовать комбинацию разных анимации с повтором некоторых анимаций.

Comment: Тогда уж `self.ani_1.finished.connect(self.ani_1.start)` :) А вы хотите зациклить всю эту анимацию?

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, что надо более кратко записать?

Answer (score 0):

Для повтора анимаций можно использовать метод [setLoopCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#loopCount-prop)

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.wid.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        self.wid.resize(100, 100)

        # animation
        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.group.setLoopCount(10)

        self.ani_1 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_1.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_1.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_1.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutSine)
        self.ani_1.setStartValue(0)
        self.ani_1.setEndValue(100)

        self.ani_2 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.ani_2.setDuration(1000)
        self.ani_2.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change)
        self.ani_2.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InSine)
        self.ani_2.setStartValue(100)
        self.ani_2.setEndValue(0)

        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_1)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.ani_2)

        self.start_fun()

    def value_change(self, value):
        self.wid.move(0, value)

    def start_fun(self):
        self.group.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```